Deploy project astro on cpanel
How to deploy an astro project in a subfolder? Since it does not recognize the files that I have in the public folder, it is a static website in cpanel, would I have to configure some parameters? I always have that problem

"Since it does not recognize the files" - what does that mean? Who is "it"?

see https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/configuration-reference/#base
